# Present an NSPopover Modally Without Sound on Close

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

Does anyone know how I would go about presenting an `NSPopover` modally without having the error sound on close?

I'm currently doing this to show the popover:

```swift
let popover = NSPopover()
popover.delegate = self
popover.contentViewController = contentController
popover.behavior = .transient
popover.show(relativeTo: self.bounds, of: self, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.maxY)
NSApplication.shared.runModal(for: popover.contentViewController!.view.window!)
```

This currently works well except for the fact that when I close the popover by clicking on the original window, I get an error sound from macOS. How can I prevent this sound from getting played but still present the popover modally?

Thanks :)

Comment: What happens when you remove `runModal`?

Comment: If I remove runModal, the background window accepts interaction (such as scrolling a scrollview). The desired effect is that the background window doesn't accept interaction until I click on it at which point the `NSPopover` gets dismissed.

Comment: That's how a popover works. A sheet is modal.

Comment: It’s not modal because you can still interact with the window that presents it such as scrolling on scroll views. Manually making the popover modal causes a sound to be played when pressing on the background window, an effect that I want to turn off

Comment: Have you tried capturing the mouse event with a local event monitor (`NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching:handler:)`)?

Comment: This worked! If you add your comment as an answer then I'll accept it :)